# Error in instaling dplyr package in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am installing dplyr package and I got the following error. Can anybody tell me what should I do to install this package properly?

My session info is:

sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

```
> devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
Downloading github repo hadley/dplyr@master
Installing dplyr
'/usr/lib64/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/RtmpoV0tCa/devtools34c45fda22d7/hadley-dplyr-cd91f33'  \
  --library='/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1'  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ...
** libs
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/tuple.hpp:33:0,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/allocate.hpp:27,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/buckets.hpp:15,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/table.hpp:10,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/equivalent.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:17,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered_map.hpp:16,
                 from ../inst/include/dplyr.h:32,
                 from RcppExports.cpp:4:
/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp: In function ‘typename boost::tuples::access_traits<typename boost::tuples::element<N, boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> >::type>::const_type boost::tuples::get(const boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT>&)’:
/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:228:45: warning: typedef ‘cons_element’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
   typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME impl::type cons_element;
                                             ^
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c address.cpp -o address.o
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c arrange.cpp -o arrange.o
In file included from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/tuple.hpp:33:0,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/allocate.hpp:27,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/buckets.hpp:15,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/table.hpp:10,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/equivalent.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:17,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered_map.hpp:16,
                 from ../inst/include/dplyr.h:32,
                 from arrange.cpp:1:
/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp: In function ‘typename boost::tuples::access_traits<typename boost::tuples::element<N, boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> >::type>::const_type boost::tuples::get(const boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT>&)’:
/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:228:45: warning: typedef ‘cons_element’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
   typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME impl::type cons_element;
                                             ^
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c between.cpp -o between.o
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c bind.cpp -o bind.o
In file included from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/tuple.hpp:33:0,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/allocate.hpp:27,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/buckets.hpp:15,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/table.hpp:10,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/equivalent.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:17,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered_map.hpp:16,
                 from ../inst/include/dplyr.h:32,
                 from bind.cpp:1:
/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp: In function ‘typename boost::tuples::access_traits<typename boost::tuples::element<N, boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> >::type>::const_type boost::tuples::get(const boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT>&)’:
/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:228:45: warning: typedef ‘cons_element’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
   typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME impl::type cons_element;
                                             ^
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c combine_variables.cpp -o combine_variables.o
combine_variables.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* combine_vars(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, Rcpp::ListOf<Rcpp::Vector<13, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >)’:
combine_variables.cpp:99:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for (int j = 0; j < vars.size(); ++j) {
                                   ^
combine_variables.cpp:135:42: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
           if (pos < 1 || pos > vars.size())
                                          ^
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c distinct.cpp -o distinct.o
In file included from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/tuple.hpp:33:0,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/allocate.hpp:27,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/buckets.hpp:15,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/table.hpp:10,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/equivalent.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:17,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered_map.hpp:16,
                 from ../inst/include/dplyr.h:32,
                 from distinct.cpp:1:
/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp: In function ‘typename boost::tuples::access_traits<typename boost::tuples::element<N, boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> >::type>::const_type boost::tuples::get(const boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT>&)’:
/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:228:45: warning: typedef ‘cons_element’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
   typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME impl::type cons_element;
                                             ^
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c dplyr.cpp -o dplyr.o
In file included from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/tuple.hpp:33:0,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/allocate.hpp:27,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/buckets.hpp:15,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/table.hpp:10,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/detail/equivalent.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:17,
                 from /opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/unordered_map.hpp:16,
                 from ../inst/include/dplyr.h:32,
                 from dplyr.cpp:1:
/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp: In function ‘typename boost::tuples::access_traits<typename boost::tuples::element<N, boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> >::type>::const_type boost::tuples::get(const boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT>&)’:
/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:228:45: warning: typedef ‘cons_element’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
   typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME impl::type cons_element;
                                             ^
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:695832: Warning: partial line at end of file ignored
{standard input}:695797: Error: invalid operands (*UND* and .gcc_except_table sections) for `-'
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
make: *** [dplyr.o] Error 4
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/opt/wpusers/mkosinski/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/dplyr’
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Comment: Here is the wrong place for this. [Post a bug report to the dplyr development website.](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues)

Comment: I had similar build issues when I first tried to install `dplyr` on a server running CentOS (essentially Red Hat) - the problem ended up being that I did not have enough RAM available. After upgrading to ~1Gb of RAM it installed without issues. How much memory do you have on your machine (`[sudo] free -m`)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason why you installed it from GitHub rather than CRAN?

Comment: @nrussell I am exactly trying to install this on CentOS. It might be that cause you pinpointed! There is only 600 MB available memory on on that machine :/ I'll try to get more memory.

Comment: @nursell it worked when I upgrade to 8Gb RAM available. You can post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @nrussell.  I was running Ubuntu VM for R (since development on Windows is sketchy).  Changing from 1024 to 3072 MB fixed it.  Definitely a memory issue.  Thanks.